# post a json object with a stream image inside it from Android to REST WCF

Tags: android, json, vb.net, wcf, rest

I'm coming behind an Android developer who wrote this code to convert an image into a base 64 string and upload it to my WCF services as a IO.Stream object...

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(mUri);
if(mNameValuePairs != null){
    // creating multipart entity for sending image files 
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);         
    for(int index=0; index < mNameValuePairs.size(); index++) {
        if(mNameValuePairs.get(index).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("strmImage")) {
            // If the key equals to "_strmImage",  use FileBody to transfer the data
            /**
             * to send image as multipart uncomment this line,  currently not used
             */
//                                                  entity.addPart(mNameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), new FileBody(new File (mNameValuePairs.get(index).getValue())));
        /**
         * convert image into byte array
         */
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mNameValuePairs.get(index).getValue(), options);
            options.inSampleSize = MainActivity.calculateInSampleSize(options,  //downsampling
                    300, 300);
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mNameValuePairs.get(index).getValue(), options); 
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
            byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT); //converting to base 64 string 
            // making the json object and storing it in mPostdata                                           
            mPostdata = new JSONStringer().object()
                    .key("thisImage")
                    .object()
                        .key("UserID").value("163")
                        .key("UserDrugImageID").value("")
                        //.key("Filename").value(mNameValuePairs.get(index).getValue())
                        .key("Filename").value("test.jpg")
                        .key("SetID").value("2ebcbba3-36bb-49ec-8625-43d60fb730ee")
                        .key("strmImage").value(image_str)
                        .endObject().toString();
            Log.e("", mPostdata);

            /**
             * to send image as String body uncomment this line, currently not used 
             */
//                                                  entity.addPart(mNameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), new StringBody(image_str));        
            /**
             * to send image as String body uncomment this line, currently not used 
             */
//                                  entity.addPart(mNameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), new ByteArrayBody(byte_arr, mNameValuePairs.get(index).getValue()));       

        } else {
             // Normal string data
            entity.addPart(mNameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), new StringBody(mNameValuePairs.get(index).getValue()));
        }
    }
    /**
     * setting multipart entity to httppost object, currently not used 
     */
//                                          post.setEntity(entity);

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(mPostdata);
    se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");//text/plain;charset=UTF-8                  
    se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

    post.setEntity(se);
/*                                          post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");*/
}
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
mServerResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

I wrote the WCF REST services, including this method which accepts a complex object:

```
<OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", UriTemplate:="drugImage/add", RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, responseformat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)> _
Function InsertUserDrugImage(ByVal thisImage As dcUserDrugImage) As dcOperationStatus

Public Function InsertUserDrugImage(ByVal thisImage As dcUserDrugImage) As dcOperationStatus Implements AndroidIService.InsertUserDrugImage
```

During debug, I see that this is the object I am sending:

```
{"thisImage":{"UserID":"163","UserDrugImageID":"","Filename":"test.jpg","SetID":"2ebcbba3-36bb-49ec-8625-43d60fb730ee","strmImage":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUAAAADwCAIAAAD+Tyo8AAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U\/gAAAKh0lEQVR4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\nDARGwEBgBAwE9j9cgtl23\/xr3AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\n"}
```

here is the datacontract for dcUserDrugImage...

```
<Serializable()> _
<DataContract> _
Public Class dcUserDrugImage
    Private _UserDrugImageID As String
    Private _UserID As String
    Private _SetID As String
    Private _url As String
    Private _Filename As String
    Private _strmImage As Stream

    <DataMember(IsRequired:=False)>
    Public Property UserDrugImageID() As String
        Get
            Return _UserDrugImageID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _UserDrugImageID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember(IsRequired:=True)>
    Public Property UserID() As String
        Get
            Return _UserID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _UserID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember(IsRequired:=True)>
    Public Property SetID() As String
        Get
            Return _SetID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _SetID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember(IsRequired:=True)>
    Public Property Filename() As String
        Get
            Return _Filename
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Filename = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember(IsRequired:=False)>
    Public Property url() As String
        Get
            Return _url
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _url = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember(IsRequired:=True)>
    Public Property strmImage() As Stream
        Get
            Return _strmImage
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Stream)
            _strmImage = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal thisDrugImage As UserDrugImage)
        _UserDrugImageID = thisDrugImage.UserDrugImageID
        _UserID = thisDrugImage.UserID
        _SetID = thisDrugImage.SetID
        _url = thisDrugImage.url
        _Filename = thisDrugImage.ImageFileName
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        sb.Append("User ID: ")
        If Not UserID = Nothing Then
            sb.Append(UserID)
        Else
            sb.Append("null")
        End If

        sb.Append(", SetID: ")
        If Not UserID = Nothing Then
            sb.Append(SetID)
        Else
            sb.Append("null")
        End If

        sb.Append(", Filename: ")
        If Not UserID = Nothing Then
            sb.Append(Filename)
        Else
            sb.Append("null")
        End If

        sb.Append(", Size of Image Stream: ")
        If Not strmImage Is Nothing Then
            sb.Append(strmImage.Length.ToString)
        Else
            sb.Append("0")
        End If

        Return sb.ToString
    End Function

End Class

<System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownType(GetType(dcUserDrugImage))> _
<CollectionDataContract()>
Public Class dcDrugImageCollection
    Inherits List(Of dcUserDrugImage)

End Class
```

The error I am getting right now is:

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. 

The exception message is 'Cannot create an abstract class.'. 

See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </p>
      <p>   at system.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.nativeGetUninitializedObject(RuntimeType type)...
```

been banging my head against the wall all day on this one, have tried 39485783475 different things, just gonna take a break and hope one of you sees something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `Stream` that is giving you problems.  It is Abstract.  Consider making that a byte array instead.  Or mark it as [not for serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, changing strmImage property to type String ended up being what worked.  I then just convert the Base64 string over to an image and store it on the server.